# Dynamically change the action of href using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a newbie to angular, and I'm playing around with it to try and understand how things work. I have an href as part of the template of a directive and an action associated with clicking the link. I would like to know how I can change the action when the user clicks on the link. I tried using a link function in my template, but I couldn't even get it to fire a message to the console.

Here is my link function:

```
var linkFunction = function(scope) {
    scope.$watch(scope.loggedin, function() {
        console.log('Here');
      });
  };
```

Any pointers? Or is there a better way.
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link function is part of directive. You can use an `ng-click` directive in the anchor tag in the template and provide its implementation in the linking function of the directive.

```
//template
<a href="" ng-click="doThis()">Click Me </a>

//Link function in directive
function(scope) {
    scope.doThis = function() {
        console.log("doing this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot easier than I thought.